# Broken pipe with busybox

Tags: busybox

I have written a script which executes in init-bottom within the initram. So it uses busybox for the commands. I included gzip from my distro to initram (gzip 1.5 went to /bin).

This is causing a "broken pipe"-error. I do not understand why:

```
find . -depth -print0|pax -wv0|/bin/gzip -c -1 ->${somewhere}/archive.pax.gz
```

I can use the -z option of pax instead of the gzip pipe: The same broken pipe. Using busybox gzip instead of /bin/gzip does the job. But why?

Comment: Does `/bin/gzip` work correctly ? Can you give us the output of `ldd /bin/gzip` ?

Comment: What's the exit status of the `gzip` process? (`echo $?` after the pipeline)